# How to solve the following problem regarding continuity and differentiability?

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

> [image]

I am trying to solve this problem. From the given equation, we can write $$(f+g)^2=(f'+g')^2$$ From this how to proceed?

Answer (score 1):

Hints: $(f-f')(f+f')=(g'-g)(g'+g)=(f +f')(f+f'+2g)$. Consider the possibilities $f+f'=0$ and $f-f'=f+f'+2g$ (or $f'=-g$). [We cannot say that one of these must hold identically but we are  only trying to find a particular solution to the problem].  Now $f'=-g$ gives $f=g'$ from the second equation so $f''=-f$. This leaves with only  a few possibilites for $f$ and $g$ and you should be able to come up with one pair $(f,g)$ satisfying all the desired properties.